# If there is a version of Kojiki in Japanese kana online

Tags: discussion, resources

Wondering if there is a Japanese kana version of [Kojiki](http://www.sacred-texts.com/shi/kj/index.htm) online, perhaps with inline translations.

Comment: Can you clarify what you're looking for? *Kojiki* is primarily written in Classical Chinese, so a *kana* version by necessity can only be for a Japanese translation of *Kojiki*. You're looking for an English translation of a Japanese translation of *Kojiki* written in *kana*?